# How do I reference a named template defined in library chart in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an application chart and a library chart defined in the following file structure:

```
project-root/
 |- my-chart/
 |   |- charts/
 |   |- templates/
 |   |   |- config-map.yaml
 |   |- Chart.yaml
 |- mylib
     |- charts/
     |- templates/
     |   |- my-config-map.yaml
     |- Chart.yaml
```

`mylib/Chart.yaml` is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: mylib
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: library
version: 0.1.0
```

`my-chart/Chart.yaml` is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: my-chart
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
dependencies:
  - name: mylib
    version: 0.1.0
    repository: file://../mylib
```

After running `helm dependencies update my-chart` the `my-chart/charts` folder contains `mylib-0.1.0.tgz` and the `my-chart/Chart.lock` file is created with the following content:

```yaml
dependencies:
- name: mylib
  repository: file://../mylib
  version: 0.1.0
digest: sha256:6183cdec0f0abe3e11c6bea32ec6077e4d693cb4819f90727930fb2916641f54
generated: "2023-07-14T14:00:14.783583108+10:00"
```

So far so good.

The `mylib/templates/config-map.yaml` file defines a named template:

```yaml
{{- define "mylib.my-config-map" -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: foobar
data:
  foo.yaml:
    hello: world
{{- end -}}
```

The `my-chart/templates/my-config-map.yaml` file includes this template:

```yaml
{{- include "mylib.my-config-map" . -}}
```

When I run `helm lint my-chart` I get the following error:

> [ERROR] templates/: template: my-chart/templates/config-map.yaml:1:4: executing "my-chart/templates/config-map.yaml" at <include "mylib.my-config-map" .>: error calling include: template: no template "mylib.my-config-map" associated with template "gotpl"

Helm version is 3.12.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if Helm doesn't necessarily scan `templates/*.yaml` files for named templates when rendering other template files.  If you move the helper function into a `templates/_*.tpl` file (and run `helm dep up` in the parent chart) does it work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. It was the leading underscore that did the trick. The docs I was following mentioned it as a convention, not a necessity. I can stop banging my head against that particular wall now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helm ignores files in library charts that don't begin with underscores.

In the subchart, you have a template file `config-map.yaml`; you need to rename this to begin with an underscore.  Since the file itself doesn't output content but only contains template definitions, you might name it `_config_map.tpl`.

In the Helm source, a [`isTemplateValid` function](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/863bc74e5ad090b97f69dcb643be8d969b07e7cf/pkg/engine/engine.go#L408-L413) includes a specific check that file names in library charts have to begin with underscores.  If that check fails, [the file is ignored](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/863bc74e5ad090b97f69dcb643be8d969b07e7cf/pkg/engine/engine.go#L394-L396) when Helm goes to build up the content to render templates.

The Helm documentation on [Library Charts](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/) doesn't clearly state this.  The only comment on file naming is this (emphasis mine):

> In the `templates/` directory, any file that begins with an underscore(_) is not expected to output a Kubernetes manifest file. So **by convention**, helper templates and partials are placed in a `_*.tpl` or `_*.yaml` files.

That "by convention" text implies you should put named templates in files with names beginning with underscore, but it doesn't explicitly say any other files are outright ignored.

Comment: Thanks. It was that "by convention" that tripped me up.